# How do you place frames on the corners of a building?

Tags: 7-days-to-die

I have a tower I am building, and I surrounded the edges with iron bars to block spiders/shoot from. My problem is that I can't completely surround the edges of my tower with iron bars because it is impossible to place any kind of thing on the corners.

Currently I create makeshift wooden frame saffholding above my traps to reach the edges of my tower, but it is very tedious.

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot so I can get a better idea of what exactly you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to rotate iron bars using the rotate button until they place themselves diagonally. They won't smoothly connect with the other bars, but they functionally get the job done.

Example:

Comment: If the OP is talking about keeping out spider zombies, I believe they are talking about having them placed horizontally. There's an issue with targetting the "edge" of the iron bars when its not a solid/visual thing, see my answer below. (OP correct me if I'm wrong please.)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact issue. The problem is that the visual part of the iron bars is not the same as it's "hit box". So in order to place the iron bars in the corner of an outside wall, you need to target with your cursor where the edge would be if it was a solid frame, not where you actually see the bar. I had the same issue trying to place torches on two sides of my iron bars as well.

Hopefully that makes sense, if not I can throw up a screenshot (not in the game right now) to further explain what I mean.